# How do I prove that this surface is regular?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Show that the set:

$ S=(\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}; (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2 \} - \{(0,0,0) \} )$

is a regular surface.

I've tried use the regular value theorem with $f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2-a^2x^2-b^2y^2-c^2z^2$

Finding the partial derivatives:

$f_x=4x(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2a^2x, f_y=4y(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2b^2y,f_z=4z(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2c^2z$

I need to get to that $0$ is a regular value, but i don't know how to show that because $f_x(0)=f_y(0)=f_z(0)=0$.

I appreciate your collaboration.

Comment: But $(0,0,0)$ has been removed from the domain. Show that there is no other point where all the partials vanish.

Comment: @TedShifrin using that, what guarantees that this is a regular surface?

Comment: You're applying the regular value theorem on $\Bbb R^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, well, but i have a problem because exist another point $(0,0,\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}})$ where the partial vanish.

Comment: The question is whether there are any points of $S$ where all the partials vanish! There are other points besides the one you gave, but are they on $S$?